# How can i wait until the every process finished in keyevents in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I create a keyevent which if I push key "A" it will do the function A().The process of A() will last for 2s. I want to wait until the every process finished if i press the key so quickly just like 4times/2s. I test and found that if i press the key in 4times/2s, it will do the process in later keypress events firstly.How can i wait until the every process finished in keyevents? I have to try to use thread and mutex. But something wrong. It's my first time to use mutex.I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
int g = 0;
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
 int keyCode = event->key();
 if(keyCode == Qt::Key_A) {
    qDebug() << "da";
    a->start();
 }
}


void MyThread::run()// i try to block the second time process while press the key so quickly
{

  mutex->lock();
  ...//process:last for 2s
  g++;
  mutex->unlock();
}
```

Comment: What is your thread supposed to do? I don't see why would you need a thread for this. Just maintain a counter of started processes. Use the [`QProcess::finished`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished) signal to be informed when a process is finished. Decrement the counter when you receive such signal. When the counter reaches 0, you will know that all processes have been finished. Though I don't see what is the point in all of this. It would be helpful if you explained your program a little bit.

Comment: i have updated the code.For example, i want to update the value of g after 2s process in A(). However,if i press the key so fast, it haven't update the g and receive the new key event and do the execute A() from the first line again. So i want set a mutex to prevent new event come and make sure it can go through the A() and update g.But the code not wor

Comment: Why do you want to update `g` two seconds after you start a process? Why can't it be updated immediately? You should explain in more detail what are you trying to achieve, because right now it makes no sense. If you want to block a keyevent while a process is running, just [check the state of the process](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#state) in your keyevent.

Comment: Beacuse i have set a timer to do a processing by using g for 2s, before updating it. So i want to save all keyevents in the queue and execute one by one every 2s( wait until the process finished do next)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right, you use want action A() to be executed on button A pressed. However, you do action A() in a separate thread, because you don't want to block the GUI thread and freeze your UI.

If you don't want to "skip" button pushes the solution is simple:

1. Create some dummy `QObject` called `context`. 
   `QObject* context = new QObject;`
2. Get `QThread` called `thread` up and running. 
   `QThread* thread = new QThread{ this }; thread->start(); ...`
3. Then move the `context` to the `thread` with
   `object->moveToThread(thread)`.
4. Create signal in your `MainWindow` class, say `runA()`.
5. Connect this signal with with `A()` action: 
   `connect(this, &MainWindow::runA, context, [] () { A(); });`
6. Each time button "A" is pressed just emit this signal: `emit runA();`

Each time the signal is emitted, an event for action `A(`) to be executed is posted to `threads event loop. All events **will be processed in order** they are posted.

---

```
#pragma once

#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QKeyEvent>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QThread* thread;
    QObject* context;

public:
    MainWindow()
        : thread{ new QThread },
          context{ new QObject }
    {
        context->moveToThread(thread);
        connect(this, &MainWindow::doAction, context, [this] () {
            Action();
        });
        thread->start();
    }
    ~MainWindow() {
        context->deleteLater();
        thread->deleteLater();
    }

signals:
    void doAction();

public:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
    {
        int keyCode = event->key();
        if(keyCode == Qt::Key_A) {
            emit doAction();
        }
    }

    void Action() {
        qDebug() << "Action is being executed.";
        QThread::currentThread()->sleep(2); // imitate some long calculation
    }
};
```

No matter how quickly you press button "A". "Action is being executed." will be printed with exactly 2 second interval and exactly the number of times button was pressed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in my case, i want to save all keyevents in the queue  and execute one by one every 2s( wait until the process finished do next). For example, i press the key 2 times/s and one process will last 2s. So in 2s i have pressed the key 4 times. And i want to save these 4 events in the queue, and execute one by one every 2s.

Comment: Connect this signal with with A() action: connect(this, &MainWindow::runA, context, [] () { A(); }); cannot work

Comment: @MotoJack, Ok, I see that first part is not an option for you. But why "connect this signal with with `A()` action" cannot work?

Comment: I gave `[] () { A(); }` just as an placeholder. See my test working example.

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is to use `QtConcurrent::run` on a thread pool with just one thread in it. This absolves you from having to manage the lifetime of the thread, an expensive resource - e.g. it will be disposed of after it has been unused for some time to free up resources.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/single-job-lambda-45913311
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtConcurrent>

class LogWindow : public QPlainTextEdit {
   Q_OBJECT
   QThreadPool m_pool;
   int g = {}; // can be accessed from the worker thread only
   void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent * event) override {
      if (event->key() == Qt::Key_A)
         QtConcurrent::run(&m_pool, this, &LogWindow::method);
      QPlainTextEdit::keyReleaseEvent(event);
   }
   /// This method must be thread-safe. It is never reentered.
   void method() {
      QThread::sleep(2); // block for two seconds
      g++;
      emit done(g);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void done(int);
public:
   LogWindow(QWidget * parent = {}) : QPlainTextEdit{parent} {
      appendPlainText("Press and release 'a' a few times.\n");
      m_pool.setMaxThreadCount(1);
      connect(this, &LogWindow::done, this, [this](int val){
         appendPlainText(QString::number(val));
      });
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   LogWindow w;
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what's required:

- if you want to launch a thread for each key pressed use `QtConcurrent::run(A);` without any mutex inside `A()`
- if you want to execute `A()` for each key pressed but not at the same time use `QtConcurrent::run(A);` with a mutex inside `A()` (like you did)

Comment: i have updated the code.For example, i want to update the value of g after 2s process in A(). However,if i press the key so fast, it haven't update the g and receive the new key event and do the execute  A() from the first line again. So i want set a mutex to prevent new event come and make sure it can go through the A() and update g.But the code not work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)